# Dynamics CRM Mobile App - Some fields Are locked in Mobile CRM App

Tags: dynamics-crm, mobile-application, dynamics365-app-mobile

In the Mobile App, There are two fields locked out of 10 fields when the Mobile App goes offline mode. When we gets online, those fields are now unlocked. it only happens when the the Mobile Phone goes offline

I have checked the below discussion for solving these issues, but I could not.

https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/prashantshuklamscrm/archive/2016/09/26/ms-crm-2016-mobile-app-configuration

And I found that those two fields are look up fields.

Answer (score 1):

Check you have enabled those entities in the lookup for offline mobile mode.

[Work offline with Dynamics 365 for phones and tablets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/mobile-app/v8/go-mobile/work-offline)

> **Mobile offline capabilities for end users**
>
> - Lookup supported to offline records: Look up are supported for the entities that are mobile offline enabled. All the entities
>     participating in the lookup should be mobile offline enabled.

Comment: Hi James, really appreciated your answer. it was initially those entities are not enabled for mobile offline. even though i enabled them for offline mode, it did not work. Then i found our from the below blogs, the offline look up fields are not supported by Mobile App
https://crmbusiness.wordpress.com/2016/05/12/crm-2016-default-crm-mobile-app-works-fully-offline-and-the-limitations-of-previous-offline-versions/

Comment: @Suga, nice, you should add an answer to your own question then!

Answer (score 1):

the offline look up fields are not supported by Mobile App